# Jquery hover function doesnt run on dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works successfully,

```
$('[rel=notif]').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
$(this).find('.solnotifkara').css({"opacity":"0.46"});
  },
    mouseleave: function () {
$(this).find('.solnotifkara').css({"opacity":"0.36"});
    }
});
```

However, if its dynamically added, its not working. I have a click function that works for dynamically added elements,

```
$(document.body).on('click', '[rel="like"]' ,function(){

alert("works");

});
```

How can I make hover function work for dynamically added elements ?

Comment: `$(document.body).on('hover', '[rel="notif"]'`?

Comment: You need to use `$(document)` instead `$(document.body)`.

Comment: @muhammed why ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(document).on({
  mouseenter: function () {
    $(this).find('.solnotifkara').css({opacity:0.46});
  },
  mouseleave: function () {
    $(this).find('.solnotifkara').css({opacity:0.36});
  }
}, "[rel=notif]");  // <<<<< delegate here your dynamic element
```

```js
$(document).on({
  mouseenter: function () {
    $(this).find('.solnotifkara').css({opacity:0.2});
  },
  mouseleave: function () {
    $(this).find('.solnotifkara').css({opacity:1});
  }
}, "[rel=notif]");  // <<<<< delegate here your dynamic element


// for test only:
$("button").on("click", function(){
  $("body").append('<p><a rel="notif">This is a <span class="solnotifkara">note</span>.</a></p>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>GENERATE</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was curious when I saw you've changed the opacity but now I see that they're updated ;)

Comment: You're welcome! @user3304007 yes... I was just trying to avoid comments from other users like "hey this does not work" since the barely noticable opacity change :)